# Android app dynamically loading data and adding a forward and back button

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I’m very new to android studio.
I intend to create an app where I’m storing my data in cloud firestore. My app should dynamically load the data from backend, display it in “n” number of fragments. These fragments should be stacked where in I can use my back/ forward buttons to move sequentially through the loaded data. (Like a book)

I have read many articles, but have not come across a solution or an approach I could take. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have succeeded in getting the data from Firestore. But my issue is storing it and parsing through it sequentially. Every fragment/activity should have the same layout but just the textview should change the data when the forward and back buttons are pressed.

Comment: I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-android-app-using-multiple-firebase-products-in-kotlin-16aade81ffec) might help.